# How to share Private video with chosen users?

Tags: youtube

When I upload a video in my Brand account and mark it as Private, I do not get to set the list of Google users who will have access to it. The description of Private access says it will be accessible to me and people I choose. But how do I choose?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As i know private video will be not available in youtube search listing. while anyone can see ur video if u share the video url

Comment: Private means only those you invite to view the video can view it (they must have their own Youtube accounts and the maximum number is 50 usernames). Your video will not come up under any search results or your channel list. If you try to share it with someone who wasn't invited, they will not be able to connect to it.

Comment: How to Invite those 50 users?